# Secure alternative of HTTP request verb (GET, POST) in PHP

Tags: php, security, http, https

I read below information in PHP.net documentation about the HTTP request verb:

> The chosen HTTP request verb (e.g. POST, GET) does not necessarily
>   make the request "secure". Any information that is not transmitted
>   over an encrypted channel (using SSL, i.e. HTTPS) is transmitted in
>   plan text.
>
> For secure transport of sensitive/private information over HTTP
>   consider using SSL as this prevents eve's dropping of the information
>   transmitted over HTTP.

What does it mean? Are method - GET / POST not secure? If yes, how to use SSL for secure transport of sensitive information over HTTP?

Comment: Every HTTP method is insecure because every HTTP message is sent in cleartext regardless of the method verb used. The only way to protect your data is to use an encrypted connection (https://). Period.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP is not secure because the packets are being sent in plain-text. HTTPS uses an encryption method on both sides so the data is secure unless a third party has access to a private key to decrypt the message.

For HTTPS you need a private key and a certificate, either self-signed or from one of many certificate issuing companies. Once you have one you can tell your webserver to use this certificate and encrypt all communication if send over the appropriate port. The HTTP port is 80 by default and the browser will automatically assume you are querying port 80 if you do not supply a port like here `http://google.com/`. That actually is `http://google.com:80/`.

The SSL (HTTPS) port is 443 and will be automatically assumed when you point your browser to e.g. `https://google.com/`. This means you need to make sure the website is serving it's content on port 443 or it will not be encrypted.

There is a vast amount of tutorials that will guide you through the process of making your webserver use an SSL certificate.

An example here: http://www.apache.com/tag/apache-ssl-tutorials/

Comment: Running application in HTTPS will solve the security issue of HTTP request verb?

Comment: @ursitesion The request verb has **NOTHING** to do with security. Every HTTP message is equally visible to anyone who cares to read it regardless of the method verb used. The *only* way to secure your data is to correctly deploy encryption (https://).

Comment: @rdlowrey: Can you please provide your answer in details?

Comment: @ursitesion There's nothing more to answer. If you don't want anyone/everyone between the client and server machines to have access to the data in your HTTP messages the only option is to encrypt those messages using SSL/TLS. No HTTP method is "secure" because all HTTP messages are transmitted in cleartext. To protect this data you must layer an encryption protocol on top of the TCP connection used to carry the HTTP messages. This is how every `https://` resource you see on the internet works.

Answer (score 0):

Take the Google Search as an example: if you search "foobar" on Google, the address bar will show something like

```
http://www.google.com/search?q=foobar
```

so the user immediately sees that info in plaintext (this is the GET method).

Now, imagine that you are logging in to a website. That will probably use the POST method and on the address bar you will see

```
http://www.example.com/login.php
```

The username and password are not shown directly to the user but are sent in the request body.

However, both POST and GET request are still sent in plaintext to the server, so an attacker on the network can "sniff" the connection and steal them.

Using SSL secures URLS, headers, page body and even the server address, so an attacker will only see random data.

What the PHP documentation tries to teach is that even if the user can't see the values on the address bar, this doesn't mean that the values are in some manner encrypted.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good answer, however the server address is still visible (destination IP).

Answer (score 0):

whenever a webpage using

```
(GET/POST method)
```

is transmitting values without using

```
SSL/HTTPS
```

the data is transmitted as plain text this happens always.

Main difference between GET AND POST forms using POST does not show the values in URL (but it is transmitted as plain text) whereas GET displays the values in URL (transmitted as plain text).

answer for your another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117315/understanding-ssl)