# Sign a CSR with keytool

Tags: ssl, keytool

I have to create an SSL connection between a client and a server. I've created a keypair and signed my public key with my private key. The server won't trust this so I need to get it signed by a CA. I presume that the server will trust a certificate which has been signed by the same CA as was used to sign its own certificate. How do I do the business of creating the signed certificate with keytool? Sorry if this is duplicated information on the Oracle website, but for some reason their pages keep breaking my internet browser.

knowledge so far is based on answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117315/understanding-ssl)

Answer (score 1):

> I presume that the server will trust a certificate which has been signed by the same CA as was used to sign its own certificate.

Correcting your assumption here: A system trusts various major Certificate Authorities (CA) by default (eg: GeoTrust, Entrust, OpenTrust, Verisign, etc...). When you get your CSR signed by any of these known CA's, the server will trust by default, not just by the CA that signed the server's certificate.

What you could do to test your SSL connection between the client and the server is to work with self-signed certificates.

> I've created a keypair and signed my public key with my private key

You shouldn't be doing this as a client. The server is supposed to do this. If the server is working with self-signed certificates, they need to provide the client with that certificate, so that the clients can trust them to make the SSL connection.

As a server, you could use the `keytool` to create a self-signed certificate. When you are generating a keypair using keytool, it will ask you few attributes like `commonName`, `organizationName`, etc... using these attributes, the keytool will create a self-signed certificate and associate it with the private key. All you have to do is export this certificate using the `keytool -exportcert` command. Once you have done this part, you would use this certificate to secure the server.

Once the server is secured, the server should give or the client this certificate, because it is self-signed and the client's system will not trust it until you explicitly trust it. If the server has secured using a certificate signed by a CA, it need not provide the client with any certificate, because, if it is a known CA, it will already be trusted by the client system.